# Trouble compiling with javac

Tags: json, javac

I have two classes I am working with at the moment, Ingredient and IngredientServices. I have no issues compiling the Ingredient class but I cant seem to compile the other without getting errors at the lines where I attempt to create Ingredient objects even though they are in the same package/directory.
They are both located in:

C:\progs\com\cs330\

[CMD errors - *click me*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlmTt.jpg)

IngredientServices.java

```
package com.cs330;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Path("ws2")
public class IngredientServices {

@Path("/ingredients")
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getIngredients() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    String connectStr="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddb";
    String username="*****";
    String password="*****";
    String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver);

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password);

    PreparedStatement preStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient");

    ResultSet rs= preStatement.executeQuery();

    Ingredient ing = new Ingredient();
    Ingredient[] ingArray = new Ingredient[100];
    int i=0;

    while (rs.next()) {
        ing = new Ingredient(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("name"),rs.getString("category"));
        ingArray[i] = ing;
        i++;
    }

    ingArray = Arrays.copyOf(ingArray,i);

return Arrays.toString(ingArray);
 }
```

Ingredient Class:

```
package com.cs330;

public class Ingredient {

private int id;
private String name;
private String category;

public Ingredient() {
id = 0;
name = null;
category = null;

}

public Ingredient(int id, String name, String category){
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.category = category;

}

public Ingredient(String name, String category){
id = 0;
this.name = name;
this.category = category;

}

  public String toString(){
    return (id + ": " + name + "( " + category + ") ");
}

}
```

Comment: We ask that you (1) include **the exact error** in your question; (2) provide **the shortest possible code** that generates that error; and (3) show results of your research/prior attempts. See the docs on building a [mcve], and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (Note that content behind a link is not considered "in" the question for purposes of that question's compliance with site rules; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122 for a discussion of the reasoning behind the policy that all content essential to answering should be included in the question itself).